# Quadratic non-residue problem

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

For a positive integer $n$, let $a(n)$ the smallest number $k>0$ such that $-n$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $k$.

Using CRT, we can prove that all values of $a(n)$ are prime powers, and every prime power except $2$ appears in the sequence.

See **[OEIS A354597](https://oeis.org/A354597)** .

It's easy to prove that $a(n)\leqslant4n-1$ (take a prime factor $p$ of $4n-1$ such that $p\equiv-1\,(\text{mod }4)$, then $-n$ is not a square modulo $p$).

But according to the figure below, it seems that we can improve the previous inequality !

How to proceed ?
[image]

Thanks !

Comment: This is conceptually related to [Artin's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots). I think this is very hard.

Comment: Thank you for your remark. Perhaps we can improve the inequality a little bit ?

Comment: Now posted to, and answered on, MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426966/quadratic-non-residue-problem